# solution to some expectation equation

Tags: probability, expected-value

We have an equation: for some $c>0$ and $g(x)$ such that $g(x)+g(-x)=1$,
\begin{align*}
\int_{\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \left[ \exp(-\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}) - \exp(-\frac{(x+1)^2}{2}) \right] g(x) = c
\end{align*}

Then, some engineering probability paper says
\begin{align*}
g(x) = \left[ 1+\exp \left( \lambda \frac{1-e^{-2x}}{1+e^{-2x}} \right)\right]^{-1}
\end{align*}
is the solution with some $\lambda < 0$.

Why is this true? I spent two days on this, but cannot figure it out unfortunately. Any hint or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't buy the solution in the paper. See below for a counterexample.

Let's recast this a bit. Given the integral equation

\begin{align*}
\int_{\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \left[ \exp(-\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}) - \exp(-\frac{(x+1)^2}{2}) \right] g(x) = c
\end{align*}

You may recognize that the terms in brackets are gaussian densities $\phi(x;\mu,\sigma)$ so we can recast this as the difference in two expected values:

\begin{align*}
\int_{\infty}^{\infty} g(x)\phi(x;1,1)dx - \int_{\infty}^{\infty} g(x) \phi(x;-1,1)dx = c
\end{align*}

Which we can represent as
$$E_{X}[g(X)] - E_{Y}[g(Y)]=c\text{ where } X\sim N(1,1),\;Y\sim N(-1,1)$$

Since $g(x)+g(-x) = 1$ we know $g(0)=\frac12$ and $g'(x) -g'(-x) =0$ which implies $g'$ is even and therefore $g(x)-\frac12$ is odd.

Let $g(x)=\frac12$, then $g(-x) + g(x) = 1$ and $g(x) - \frac12$ is the zero function on $\mathbb{R}$ which happens to be both even and odd!

Therefore,

$$E_{X}[g(X)] - E_{Y}[g(Y)]=\frac12 - \frac12  = 0$$

Here we see that $g(x) = \frac12 \iff \lambda=0$ because

$$\left[ 1+\exp \left( \lambda \frac{1-e^{-2x}}{1+e^{-2x}} \right)\right]^{-1} = \frac12 \iff \lambda = 0$$

More generally, let $c>0$. If $\lambda < 0$ then $g(x;\lambda)$ is a monotonic increasing function of $x$ that approaches a constant function as $\lambda$ approaches zero from below:

$$\lim_{\lambda \to 0^-} g(x;\lambda) = \frac12 \implies E_X[g(X)]-E_Y[g(Y)] = 0$$

And the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) as you approach $-\infty$:

$$\lim_{\lambda \to -\infty} g(x;\lambda) = H(x)\equiv \mathbb{1}_{\geq 0}(x) \implies E_X[H(X)] - E_Y[H(Y)] = $$
$$P(X>0) - P(Y>0) = \Phi(1) - \Phi(-1) \approx 0.68$$

Since $g(x;\lambda)$ is strictly increasing in $x$ for all $\lambda < 0$  and $\text{sgn } \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}g(x;\lambda)\right]= \text{sgn }x \;\;\forall \lambda < 0$, we see that as $\lambda \to 0^-$ we put increasing weight on $x>0$ and less on $x<0$ monotonically and continuously as a function of $\lambda$, hence $\lambda \to -\infty$ and $\lambda \to 0^-$ will bracket the range of this integral equation.

Taking these two extremes we see that

$$ 0 < E_X[g(X;\lambda) - E_Y[g(Y;\lambda)] < 0.68 \;\;\forall \lambda < 0$$

So the proposed function for $g$ can only accommodate $c \in (0,0.68)$, hardly $c>0$.

**EDIT:** OP confirmed that $c \in (0,0.68)$ was the actual range considered in the paper, and not simply $c>0$, in which case there is a 1-to-1 relationship between $c$ and $\lambda$.

The question that remains is how to derive this. I contend that the paper's proposed functional form for $g(x)$ is *a* solution, but not *the* solution, as there is a broader class of single-parameter functions whose parameter $\theta$ is determined by $c\in (0,0.68)$ (i.e., $\theta_{c} = f(c)$), where $f$ is determined by the choice of $g$.

From the above, we see that as long as $g\geq 0,\;g(x)+g(-x)=1$ then we are in good shape. From the way the authors set $\lambda < 0$, we can throw in that $\theta \in (a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $g$ is monotonic increasing in $x$ and

$$\lim_{\theta \to b^-} g(x;\theta) = \frac12,\;\; \lim_{\theta \to a^+}g(x;\theta) = H(x)$$

So, for example, this also works for $g$:

$$g(x;\theta) = \frac12 -\theta[1-H(x)] + \theta H(x) = \frac12 -\theta + 2\theta H(x),\;\;\theta \in \left(0,\frac12\right)$$

We can see that
$$g(x;\theta) + g(-x;\theta)= \left[\frac12 -\theta + 2\theta\right] + \left[ \frac12-\theta \right] =  1$$

And the function approaches $\frac12$ and $H(x)$ as $\theta \to 0^+,\;\;\theta \to \frac12^-$, respectively.

In fact, unlike the proposed solution, we can analytically identify $c$ produced by a given $\theta$:

$$E_X[g(X;\theta)] - E_Y[g(Y;\theta)] = $$
$$\left(\frac12 - \theta \right)P(X\leq 0)+ \left(\frac12 + \theta \right)P(X>0) -\left(\frac12 - \theta \right)P(Y\leq 0)-\left(\frac12 + \theta \right)P(Y>0)=$$

$$\left(\frac12 - \theta \right)\Phi(-1)+ \left(\frac12 + \theta \right)\Phi(1) -\left(\frac12 - \theta \right)\Phi(1)-\left(\frac12 + \theta \right)\Phi(-1)=$$

$$\Phi(1)\left[\frac12 + \theta - \frac12 + \theta\right] +   \Phi(-1)\left[\frac12 - \theta -\frac12-\theta\right] = 2\theta\left[\Phi(1)-\Phi(-1)\right]$$
$$\approx 2(.68)\theta = 1.36\theta\;\;\theta \in \left(0,\frac12\right)$$

So for this version of $g$, we get a nice linear relationship between $c$ and $\theta$, and this satisfies the requirements of the paper.

I think there must have been other considerations (e.g., smoothness or continuity) that the authors felt was necessary. But even then, there are several other options (like the [sigmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function)).

So, the reason you can't derive their answer, is because you can't -- getting to the form in the paper requires additional desiderata apart from $g(x) + g(-1)=1$ and the need for the integral formula to evaluate to some $c\in (0,0.68)$.

Comment: Yes, the range of c is exactly $(0, 0.68)$, which I missed. The solution is not for every $c$, it is only for some $c \in (0, 0.68)$
The value of $\lambda$ is indeed a function of $c$.

I am wondering how I can derive the solution.

Comment: Gotcha— we’ll that’s good :-) I don’t think you can derive this as it’s not unique. Their $g(x)$ is $a$ possible solution.It looks like any non-negative monotonic increasing function that satisfies my conditions will work. I’ll add a little edit when I get time.

Comment: I agree with you that there will be many solutions. thanks for the answer, I will look forward to your edit :)

Comment: @Jayboy -- ok, added a bit more -- gave an example of a much simpler function for $g(x)$ that still works, so it's not possible to get the solution in the paper solely from the information given .. there is something else they were considering.